# C# Multithreading - How do I create a background working task in WebApi Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, background-process, asp.net-core-webapi

***I am building a WebApi application in .NET Core 2.0.
My application runs SQL queries on a database***.

When a request is sent to the application, a SQL query is run on the database (which results in a very small dataset). Meanwhile, in the background, I have to start executing a bigger query (which might take about 15 mins. to execute) on a background thread.

This background task must keep executing even after the request has returned a response, and should notify the application after it has returned.

Can you please suggest me the best possible way to accomplisgh this?

I am using:
IIS Server as reverse proxy,
.NET Core WebApi 2.0,
Running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2012 OS.

Comment: Simplistically can use `IHostedService` or a background task scheduler library like Hangfire. In either case, you'd also need to utilize SignalR to update the client when the job completes. Other than that, your question is too broad. You'll need to do your own research and make an attempt at a solution, first.

Comment: Yeah, I'll do that. Thanks Chris Patt :)